# How to install and configure GNOME Keyring without installing full desktop environment?

Tags: server, gnome-keyring

I am trying to set up a vagrant image using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit without a desktop envionment (pure server), that contains a working GNOME Keyring. Nothing I've tried so far has worked.

Any suggestions? Is it even possible?